# Compute a formula only if another column is true

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column `A` with a series of name, and a column `B` which contains a boolean.

I want apply a formula on `A` column only if column `B` is true. The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2;FIND("_";A2)-1);A2)
```

How can I do? How can I modify my formula?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood it correctly but if you want to execute something if a special case is true I would suggest using if:

```
=IF(condition; execute if true; execute if false)
```

In you case this could be:

```
=IF(B2;IFERROR(LEFT(A2;FIND("_";A2)-1);A2); 0)
```

B2 is the Field you want it check if it is true, if B2 is a string or something else you would need to check B2==„true“

And instead of 0 you could add what you prefer to be executed in stead

Comment: I have a problem finding any reference to the Excel function `when`. Can you please provide some info? Did you want to say `if`? Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry i Mixed up the German and english Version :D it is IF I change it